# Nothing is saved when adding "too" many items to couchbase

Tags: ruby, couchbase

I've started to transfer our data from and old key-value store to couchbase (couchbase type bucket). I made the simplest possible ruby script that loops over the keys, reads the value from the old DB, and adds it to the couchbase:

```
item_count = 0
cb = Couchbase.connect(bucket:"ep", password:"secret")
cb.run do |ep|
  old_db.read do
    key = ... # next key from old DB
    json = ... # next value from old DB

    ep.set(key, json.to_s)

    item_count += 1
  end
end
puts item_count
```

I flush my bucket, then after running my script I look at the couchbase web console at the item count in ep bucket.

When I add ~2000 or less items, it all looks good. But when I add more than 2000 items, the bucket stays empty!

When I have around 1900 items in the bucket it is around 50% capacity, so it's not because it's getting full. (and even then I would expect the first items to be saved)

Comment: Have you tried `cb.flush if (item_count % 1000).zero?` right after increasing `item_count`? Sounds like a memory problem.

Comment: actually that just made things worse :( now it doesn't even work on 1900. Strange though, 'cause I would expect at least the last 900 items to see in the bucket. BTW I'm pretty sure that flush deletes all the items in a bucket, (like flush the toilette) and is not flushing the buffers to the disk or something like that.

Comment: OK, another suggestion would be to call [`stats`](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-ruby-client#stats) after, say, every 500 `set`s and examine an output. Hopefully it’ll give some suggestions. Also make sure that `quiet` mode is _off_.

Comment: IMHO quiet mode only affects gets and I only do sets.

Comment: I am not as sure about `quiet`: https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-ruby-client/blob/8c0372df0bc4b6bd2f8b5596fdcddf4f47d4d31a/lib/active_support/cache/couchbase_store.rb#L54

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a possible solution. The cauchbase documentation talks about set() and it is said that it can be used both sync, async, and from the not too well documented examples I thought that if I don't pass a block, then it's going to be sync. It seems it is not the case, so I changed my code to use callbacks:

```
def copy_next(old_db, cb, ep)
  key = old_db.next_key # next key from old DB
  if key
    json = old_db.get(key) # next value from old DB

    ep.set(key, json.to_s) do |cas, k, op|
      copy_next(old_db, cb, ep)
    end
  end
end

cb = Couchbase.connect(bucket:"ep", password:"secret")
cb.run do |ep|
  copy_next(old_db, cb, ep)
end
```